# UITableView subViews does not contain UITableViewWrapperView iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, ios11

I have created a `UIViewController` in `Storyboard` that contains a `UITableView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(self.tableView.subviews) //HERE..!!!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**Issue:** I am facing issue with `subViews` of `UITableView`.

**In iOS-10**, when executing `tableView.subviews`, I am getting `UITableViewWrapperView` as one of the elements along with other elements in the array.

But **in iOS-11**, `UITableViewWrapperView` is not available in the array returned by `tableView.subviews`.

Due to this, I am facing issue with `hitTest:withEvent:` that I have overridden on `UITableView`.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82320 See this

Comment: @PGDev what is the problem with `hitTest:withEvent:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **iOS-11**, Apple removed `UITableViewWrapperView` from the `table view` hierarchy as confirmed in the link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82320

I was facing issue with `hitTest:withEvent:` because it was earlier applied on `tableView.subviews.first` i.e. `UITableViewWrapperView`.

Now, I applied `hitTest` on the `UITableView` itself instead of its `wrapper view`, i.e.

```
class TableView: UITableView
{
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        if let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) , hitView != self
        {
            return hitView
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Finally got it working.